# dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract

Tags: error

i am facing a situation where i can't find any solution. My website was working fine till but after some autoupdate my website stopped working, after checking many tutorials now i stuck on this place. please help me with the solution ASAP. [http://www.hakkunamatatta.com/][1]

Comment: What do you mean by autoupdate? Do you upgrade any custom module ?

Answer (score 1):

The error is arising due to Magento can't find a valid read/write connection. Reasons for this may be different.

1. Do you have the file `app\etc\local.xml` file. May be this file is missing. This file is important because this is where Magento holds core write/read connection configuration.
2. Did you check file permission of your Magento installation and `local.xml` file permission ?
3. Clear `var/cahe`, `var/session` etc.
4. Check the report number in the folder `var/reports/{report_number}`. It may give you additional informations.